# Proper way to add an entity to an aggregate root in DDD

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I have an aggregate root called `Order` and I need to add a `Product` to the `Order`:

```
public class Order {
  public void AddProduct(Product p) {
  }
}
```

I'd like to ask `DDD` guidelines when it comes to this. I'm facing two questions:

1. `Product` has two properties, among others: `Product.OrderID` and `Product.Order`. In terms of `DDD`, which of these properties should I set **before calling** `Order.AddProduct`?
2. Or is it that I need to set either one of these two properties **inside** `Order.AddProduct`, something like "`p.Order = this`";

Please note that I'm using `Order` and `Product` as examples. I've been told that this relationship may not be appropriate. Thank you.

Comment: I think you're confusing some of the DDD terms. You cannot add an aggregate to an aggregate root. Should the title of the question probably be "Proper way to add an entity to an aggregate root in DDD"? That would make more sense...

Comment: I see what you're saying... Thank you! I will change now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the aggregate create the entity. This is the simplest solution for clients, because "create" and "add product" are not separated.

```
public class Order 
{
   private readonly List<Product> _products = new List<Product>();

   public Product CreateProduct(string name, Price price) 
   {
      var product = new Product(new ProductId(), name, price);
      _products.Add(product);

      return product;
   }
}
```

Note that the signature of `CreateProduct` may vary depending on your needs. E.g. in some cases you will want to provide the ID from the client, whereas in other cases the Order generates an ID for the product.

Note: you probably should have aggragate Product and OrderItem or ProductOrderItem entity. OrderItem is entity which will be added to Order. When you edit your product, OrderItems will not be modified.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a factory method. Here an example:

```
public class Order {
    public Product addProduct(
        ProductId aProductId, 
        String aDescription 
    ) {
        Product product = new Product(
            this.orderId
            aProductId, 
            aDescription
        )

        //Publish event ProductWasAddedToOrder(this.orderId, aProductId) 

        return product;
    }
}
```

Then if you want you can have a subscriber (Observer pattern) listening to the  NewItemWasAddedToOrder event which, for instance, it can display the item added in a shopping cart or something like that.

**Update**: I made a big mistake because I confused terms. When I was thinking on Product, I was imaging an Order item, something that does not exist and it is created at the moment of adding a new element to the Order, which I think can be the best way.

Imagine that in the Order you save the ProductId (a reference to the Product), on the other hand the customer who ordered that product paid 20€ for it. Two months later an admin of the system changes the price of the same product, and since you saved in the order a reference to that product if you want to check how much the customer paid that day you will get the new value instead. Saving the Product within  the Order, whenever you modify the Product you are also modifying the Order.

Therefore I would add a new Item to the Order with the specific information that the product has at that moment. The item should hold also a reference to the Product just to know how many items have been created given a specific product. Here the example:

```
public class Order {
    public OrderItem addItem(
        OrderItemId anItemId, 
        ProductId aProductId, 
        Price aPrice, 
        String aDescription 
    ) {
        OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem(
            anItemId, 
            this.orderId,
            aProductId,
            aDescription, 
            aPrice
        )

        //Publish event NewItemWasAddedToOrder(this.orderId, anItemId) 

        return orderItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. So should I pass property by property (i.e. ProductName, ProductDescription, etc.) instead of the whole object?

Comment: I've updated my answer because I misunderstood the problem at first.